# Cloud Function retrieving a value based on URL parameter

Tags: express, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a Cloud Function in node where I can return a token from a parameter.
The URL I use is... 
https://us-central1-nmnm03.cloudfunctions.net/GetAccount?taccount=Asd

my function is this... and its wrong.  I suspect I am not assigning TT properly.

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.GetAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        const t = admin.database().ref('/newaccout/'+req.query.account)
        const tt = t.child(token)
            res.send( "res is " + tt );
  });
```

req.query.account is the Key.  One of the Items in the document is token
ideally, I would like to get something like...
{"token":"23453458885"}

Could I get a node hint please... thanks

Comment: You have `t.child(token)` but it looks like the token is being assigned to `t`

Answer (score 0):

Though, I am not a firebase geek. What it seems from the documentation is that you will have two events that you can use to listen for retrieving child data. You can read further more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data). The given options are used for different cases. Please follow through the mentioned link to have clear view.

Inside your cloud function you can try doing following:

```
const t = admin.database().ref('/newaccout/'+req.query.account)
t.on('child_added', function(data) {
  res.json({
     token: data.token
  })
})
```

Or maybe like this:

```
const t = admin.database().ref('/newaccout/'+req.query.account)
t.once('value', function(snapshot) {
   //Process it like above
   //But here you will get al child elements at once
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting to query the value found at a database reference stored at t.  Unfortunately, you haven't actually performed a query yet.  tt is just yet another Reference object that points to a location in the database.  You should use the [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method on Reference to query a database location.  Also bear in mind that you are using a variable called `token`, but you haven't defined yet in your code.  To me, that looks like it would generate an error to me.

You might be well served by looking at a bunch of the [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/).